# How should I format my return statement so I don't double the answer?

Tags: java, return, computer-science

```
private String twoDigits(int value) {
    String result = "";
    {   

    if ((mMinute >= 0) && (mMinute <= 9) && (mSecond >= 0) && (mSecond <= 9)) { 
        tempmin = ("0" + mMinute ); 
        tempsec = ("0" + mSecond );
    } else
        tempmin = (mMinute + "");

    tempsec = (mSecond + " ");
    return tempin+tempsec;
```

This just doubles the output that I'm looking for and I was wondering, whether or not the issue was with the return statement or the actual method.

I need to call back to this method,  twoDigits(mMinute)+":"+twoDigits(mSecond) to get the code to display the time, but instead of being able to display 10:09:08 I keep displaying 10:0908:0908

I was wondering how I should fix my code.

Comment: you've forgotten your `{}` for `else`

Comment: what @Paul said  + use ide (intelliJ/eclipse)

Comment: @JigarJoshi Do you care to explain further how that might help the OP?

Comment: You have a `value` parameter which you never use. This is the primary reason you are seeing the duplication.

Comment: @JigarJoshi Tell the OP, not me.

Comment: You could convert the `int` value to a `String`, if it's length is less than 2, prefix with a `0`...as an alternative ;)

Answer (score 2):

Since there are a lot of tiny mistakes in your code, I'll suggest a slightly different approach. Not sure if this method works, in what I assume is Java, but give it a shot:

```
private String twoDigits(int value)
{
    return value <= 9 ? "0" + value : value;
}
```

This is actually an if/else abbreviation. Return the following: If value <= 9 then add a zero before the value, else the value.

If there's a risk of negative values being received, you could add this:

```
    return (value >= 0 && value <= 9) ? "0" + value : value;
```

First, there's Paul's comment about the {} after *else* to encompass both rows. Then, you are not actually using the *value* received by the function but rather some global variables (mMinute and mSecond). You create but never use *result*. Furthermore, your if statement says that if both mMinute AND mSecond are between 0 and 9 then both should be fixed. Since you should use *value* you only have to check that variable's range and edit it accordingly. On the row tempsec = (mSecond + " "); you add a space.. mistake? Finally, you misspelled *tempmin* on the return row.

Good luck.

Comment: There's also a { after String result = ""; that doesn't belong to anything

Answer (score 0):

Note that your method has a `value` parameter. You should use this rather than directly access the fields in your class. Perhaps it might help for you to think about the purpose of the `twoDigits()` method. It seems to me that it is supposed to take an `int` value and pad it with a leading zero if the input is only a single digit. Note that my description in the previous sentence does **not** refer to the member variables that represent minutes and seconds; it only refers to the input value.